# Should I return a 404 error on a resource resulting in empty set?

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, http-status-code-200

If I have a resource with the following endpoint that lists all items within that resource:

```
/api/v1/resources
```

This results in:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": -100
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": -999
  }
]
```

It has various filters, for example:

```
/api/v1/resources?values_gte=999
```

If the filters exclude every resource and results in an empty set:

```
[]
```

Should I return a 404 status code, or a 200 status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I return a 404 status code, or a 200 status code?

[200](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)

> You asked for the current representation of the resource identified by "/api/v1/resources?values_gte=999" so here it is: an empty [JSON array](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-5)

Notice that this is exactly what you would do if somebody requested `/foo.json`, and that file on your disk happened to contain exactly the contents `[]`

HTTP status codes are metadata identifying the semantics of the response; they are used to distinguish representations of documents (2xx Successful) from representations of errors (4xx Client Error).

The *payload* of a 404 response would be "a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.", not an empty document.